# Вычисляемые свойства

Tags: javascript, терминология

Ребята, объясните что такое **вычисляемые свойства**? Не нашел объяснения, которое могу понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это те, которые не хранят значение, а вычисляют его на основе чего-то ещё (естественно, добавленные через `defineProperty` тоже считаются):

```js
var x = {
  a: 9,
  b: 6,
  get sum() {
    return this.a + this.b
  }
}

console.log(x.sum)

x.a = -1
console.log(x.sum)
```